# pyqt not working: from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget makes python shell exit immediately

Tags: python, pyqt

I discovered this issue because the import statement for matplotlib, `import matplotlib.pyplot` was causing my python shell to exit immediately. Another user offered that I may be having problems with my pyqt installation. There is indeed something wrong with pyqt.

If I go into the python shell and just try to include this statement, `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget`, the python shell immediately closes and exits without any error message or anything.

I am using python 3 and I'm using the miniconda3 package distribution. I'm in a conda virtualenv called py_summer.
If I try to use `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget` OUTSIDE of the virtualenv, then the statement causes no problems. The matplotlib.pyplot import statement also works outside of this virtualenv.

A list of relevant packages in this virtualenv: pyqt 5.6.0, matplotlib 2.2.3, python 3.5.5...

And again, I already tried `conda remove pyqt` then reinstalled and this DID NOT resolve the issue.

Comment: `python -m trace`  is your friend. (`strace` may also be relevant, and/or gdb, if this is happening inside a C library; but first place to start is at the Python layer).

Comment: What's your operating system? Are you starting this from a terminal? Is the terminal still alive after Python abruptly exits? If so, what does `echo $?` return when run immediately at that point?

Comment: this is a windows 10 OS, I am using git bash on windows. and yes the terminal is still alive after python abruptly exists. `echo $` actually... prints a blank line... just a $ and nothing else.

Comment: `echo $?`, not `echo $`. Needs to be the **immediate** command after the exit takes place, so if you ran `echo $`, go back and reproduce the issue again.

Comment: sorry. `echo $?` output the number "5" after the python shell exiting

Comment: Hmmm. On a UNIX system, a value that low would mean we had an explicit failure rather than a death by signal. On Windows, I'm not so sure that that's true; might need to let someone with more knowledge of the platform chime in.